Using Format( "dd/mmyyyy") in sql for MS-Access VBA select causes syntax error
I'm querying a table containing a date field that is defined as general date.  Table contains records with dates in format dd/mm/yyyy ( which is standard for my location ) for 16/11/2024, 23/11/2024, 7/12/2024 and 14/12/2024.
My sql works for 16/11/2024 and 23/11/2024, retrieving records as expected.
Select for 7/12/2024 fails on the read with no records found. I think it is treating this as 12 July 2024.
I've researched use of format to explicitly define the format of the date.
Built a sql select but keep getting a syntax error when it runs.
My variable: Dim vFixtureDate as Date is calculated using general date field from another table.
SQL statement here.
sqlF = "select \* from fixtures where fixture_dt_short = #" & "Format(" & vFixtureDate & ", " & Chr(34) & "dd/mm/yyyy" & Chr(34) & ")#"

SQL looks good - msgbox shows a statement that looks correct with # at either end of the Format parameters.
When it runs, dialog box contains "Syntax error in date in query expression.
The displayed SQL statement in the dialog box contains ")'.   at the end. Closing # is missing.

Please read this article from Allen Browne http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html and use is SQL date function( in the article).

The code you posted won't work at all. Use Debug.Print to see the resulting sqlF, and add this to the question.

I had a quick look at Allen's page - will explore this when I'm free from current assignment. thanks

Simple solution in Allen's article. did the job.

Use the ISO sequence and reduce it to:
sqlF = "select * from fixtures where fixture_dt_short = #" & Format(vFixtureDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd/") & "#"


thanks. I'll research this and test the change.  I think my problem is in the way I'm building the SQL Select statement by concatenating the literals and variables, which includes the Format.

It is. For an easier approach when concatenating, consider my function CSql.

Make an independent Date format
In MS Access table data stored in date field can be retrieved in any format. The question is how we are using the date format. Some use month in left some use it in middle of the format with two digits numeric value. To make it independent make it 3-Alpha short month name(Jan, Feb, Mar...Dec).
for example
Format(vFixtureDate, "Mmm-DD-YYYY")
or
Format(vFixtureDate, "DD-Mmm-YYYY")

Value from above (Nov-20-2024 or 20-Nov-2024) will give you the same resultset in SQL statement.
Finally we can write
sqlF = "SELECT * FROM fixtures  WHERE fixture_dt_short = #" & Format(vFixtureDate, "DD-Mmm-YYYY") & "#"
or
sqlF = "SELECT * FROM fixtures  WHERE fixture_dt_short = #" & Format(vFixtureDate, "Mmm-DD-YYYY") & "#"

Implemented this code on MS Access 2016.
Thanks

1: Date values can not be retrieved in any format as they are saved as a numeric value with no format; thus they must be formatted for display or print using either a default format (from the Windows settings) or a custom format. 2: Using the format "mmm" in SQL is doomed to fail in any non-English locale, as the month abbreviations are localised.

@Gustav, In this case, date is saved in date field mentioned in the question.

Certainly it is, as date/time values always should be saved as DateTime. But there is no way to "define" a format of the saved values, as these values are numeric. A format is only applied when the values are presented, or you would not be able to read them easily.

In this case nothing is saving. Interestingly no fields of table changing. Only we use the format in the parameter value in the where condition. It works here. I  applied it in my several works.

Right, you are not saving, you are reading - and applying a dubious format to the filter to create a text expression for the numeric date value. That format will work in English environments and fail in any other, thus should be avoided, indeed not promoted. Always use the ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) which will never fail.
